# How to implement deng l when creating lazy loaded routes using createBrowserRouter of React-router-dom

Tags: lazy-loading, react-router-component

1. I created a route with the code below but I don't know how to implement login interception with lazy loading, I tried many ways.
2. The main problem is that I'm using lazy loading mode and I'm using TypeScript.
3. I also looked for related solutions on many websites, but none met my expectations.
4. There is no relevant description of this problem in the official documentation, and there is no functional code similar to the route guard in Vue-Router.

```
const NotFound = lazy(() => import("@/page/error/NotFound"));
const UserLogin = lazy(() => import("@/page/login/UserLogin"));
const PageHome = lazy(() => import("@/page/home/PageHome"));

const PageFile = lazy(() => import("@/page/file/PageFile"));

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/login",
    Component: UserLogin,
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    Component: PageHome,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        Component: PageFile,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    Component: NotFound,
  },
]);

export default router;
```

I tried the following, but failed

```
import { FC, LazyExoticComponent } from "react";

import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

interface AuthNode {
  children: LazyExoticComponent<FC>;
}

const AuthRoute: FC<AuthNode> = ({ children }) => {
  const [cookie] = useCookies<string>(["Authorization"]);
  const location = useLocation();
  if (location.pathname !== "/login" && !cookie) {
    return <Navigate to={"/login"} state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }
  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default AuthRoute;
```